# I want to apply multiple filters and change a column value accordingly in pandas [Working now]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Suppose I have a dataframe like so:

```
Fil1 Fil2                    A    B   C   D 
a    crossdev radio com      Act  1   23  324
b    crossdev webapp radio   Act  4   45  343
a    Streaming webapp radio  Act  3   23  566
a    crossdev com            Act  1   12  746
```

The Fil1 column in the actual file is really long name that I'm filtering, but here I'm referencing it as just 'a'.

The code I'm using is --

```
df.loc[(df['Fil1'] == 'a') & (df['Fil2'].str.contains('com')) , 'C'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Fil1'] == 'a') & (df['Fil2'].str.contains('com')) , 'D'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Fil1'] == 'a') & (df['Fil2'].str.contains('com')) , 'A'] = 'Fail'
```

Outputting this df to excel.

Desired Excel Output:

```
Fil1 Fil2                    A     B   C   D 
a    crossdev radio com      Fail  1   0   0
b    crossdev webapp radio   Act   4   45  343
a    Streaming webapp radio  Act   3   23  566
a    crossdev com            Fail  1   0   0
```

My code is not giving me any error but it is not even giving me desired result.
Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Does this return the appropriate True and False values? `(df['Fil1'] == 'a') & (df['Fil2']str.contains('com'))`?

Comment: @ScottBoston I didn't check that, how do I?

Comment: Am I missing something? your three lines of code produce the desired output. Is that really the desired output?

Comment: The code is working! The value that I referred to here as 'a' was a mess that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working! It had no error.
The value that I referred to here as 'a' was a mess in my real dataset that caused the problem.